# Reponsive image rows

Tags: css

I have a section which has 3 images per row. There are total 3 rows which leads to 9 images.

I want to make them responsive but can't figure out how to display all the images accordingly, currently it shows the first image and then instantly the fourth one, instead of the second one. I also tried to center them but failed, here's the screenshot of mobile view

[image: screenshot of mobile view]

My css code for the responsive view and what i've tried so far.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {

  .articles {
   margin: 50px 30px;
  }

  .article {
   left: 0;
  }

}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mhrxbqgw/2/

Comment: Create a working example by adding all necessary HTML and CSS codes.

Comment: Updated post. @ata

Answer (score 1):

Try Flexbox like this

```css
.articles {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.article {
  width: 30%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.article-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.article-title {
  font-family: "SFUI Display";
  color: #3f3f3f;
  font-size: 24px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .article {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="articles">

  <article class="article">
    <img class="article-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <h3 class="article-title">Article 1 </h3>

  </article>

  <article class="article">
    <img class="article-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <h3 class="article-title">Article 2 </h3>

  </article>

  <article class="article">
    <img class="article-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <h3 class="article-title">Article 3 </h3>

  </article>

  <article class="article">
    <img class="article-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <h3 class="article-title">Article 4 </h3>

  </article>

  <article class="article">
    <img class="article-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <h3 class="article-title">Article 5 </h3>

  </article>


  <article class="article">
    <img class="article-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <h3 class="article-title">Article 6 </h3>



  </article>

  <article class="article">
    <img class="article-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <h3 class="article-title">Article 7 </h3>



  </article>

  <article class="article">
    <img class="article-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <h3 class="article-title">Article 8 </h3>



  </article>

  <article class="article">
    <img class="article-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <h3 class="article-title">Article 9 </h3>



  </article>


</section>
```